# linear scale value between two values

Tags: javascript

I have a three values.

```
let a = 10;
let b = 200;
let c = 140;
```

I want to make the line scale chart by which straight line starting point is 10 and end point is 140.

Now I have to make the calculation by which 140 value will be lie in between the line.

```
Its like 0, 50 & 100. ) is starting point, 100 is end point and 50 is the central point.
```

So I pass the 50 percent so that it will be on the center.

I have made the UI. I just need to pass the percent value by which UI will be made.

Any suggestion for this will highly appreciable

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: Share a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right the formula you need is

```
(c-a)/(b-a)*100
```

or in javascript

```js
((c-a)/(b-a)*100).toFixed(1)+'%`
```

Comment: You have done just opposite. 
(b-a)/(c-a)*100

Comment: anyways thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: No. Look how you defined a, b and c! 

(b-a)/(c-a)*100 gets values >100. With your example values you get 146%. The correct answer, by my formula the result is 68.4%.